# jQuery clearing a textbox after validating

Tags: jquery

Feel like this should be easy but I can't get it to work.  I'm trying to validate the paste event using jQuery to ensure the user doesn't try to enter two decimals.  I'm trying to check the value, throw a toast alert, and clear the value altogether.  All of it works except clearing the value.  Here's what I've got:

```js
$('input.costTextBox').bind("paste", function(e) {
  var pastedData = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text');
  var testDecimal = testDecimals(pastedData);

  if (testDecimal.length > 1) {
    toastr["warning"]("You cannot enter more than one decimal point");
    $(this).val('');
  }
});

function testDecimals(currentVal) {
  var count;
  currentVal.match(/\./g) === null ? count = 0 : count = currentVal.match(/\./g);
  return count;
}
```

I feel like `$(this).val('')` should clear out the value but after the toast message it's still there.

Comment: Tried to prevent the event default?

Comment: Man, duh, preventdefault.  Thanks CBroe, think I've been looking at this too long.

Comment: And use `.on` ...